# Как отменить автоматическое добавление новых файлов к git в Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio

Добавляя новый файл к Git в Android Studio, по ошибке отметила чекбокс "Запомнить мой выбор". Теперь все, что нужно и не нужно отслеживается. Как отменить эту команду?

Желательно обойтись графическими средствами Android 
Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выключить авто-добавление: **Settings** -> **Version Control** -> **Confirmation** -> **When files are creating** и выбрать нужную опцию, например, **Show options before adding to version control**

Comment: Первое помогло. Второе - нет. Я оставлю здесь только первый вопрос и задам второй вопрос отдельно.